# Nginx drop when server_name does not match

Tags: http, nginx, dns, subdomain

I have two vhosts : one on `domain.tld` port 80, the other on `sub.domain.tld` port 443 with SSL on. I added a CNAME entry on my DNS server that redirects my `sub` subdomain to `domain.tld.`. 
Everything works as expected, but going to `http://sub.domain.tld` does the same as going to `http://domain.tld`, and `https://domain.tld` the same as `https://sub.domain.tld`. How can I prevent this ?

My configuration :

```
server {
    listen *:443;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name www.sub.domain.tld;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certifiate ...;
    ssl_certifiate_key ...;

    root /var/www/sub.domain.tld;
    ...
}

server {
    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.domain.tld;

    root /var/www/domain.tld;
    ...
}
```

Comment: did you try     server_name sub.domain.tld; (Without www)

Comment: Still the same without `www`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If these are your only `server` blocks, then they are also your defacto *default server* blocks for port 443 and port 80 respectively. See [this document][http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html] for details.

If you do not want this, you need to declare a default server block. A minimalist definition might be:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certifiate ...;
    ssl_certifiate_key ...;

    return 403;
}
```

The ssl certificate is required to start the Nginx service, but it can be any certificate. Also, the `ssl_certifiate` directives are inherited, so you can place the default statements in the `http` block instead.

Use `return 444;` to just close the connection with no response.

Comment: this config completely blocks the server

Comment: no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive