# Nginx serves different website (on the same sever) when using HTTPS

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have several websites hosted on the same sever. To simplify I have just 2 (`http-only.com` and `https.com`) and using nginx to handle requests.
One has SSL enabled. And another doesn't. I noticed links like this in Google Search Console `http-only.com/https_server_path` and when accessing an `http-only.com` server with `https` protocol I get requests served by an `https.com` server instead.
**https.com:**

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name https.com;
  ssl on;
}
```

**only-http.com:**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name only-http.com;
}
```

I think I should define something like a default ssl server to handle ssl for `http.com`, but don't know how to do it properly. I guess nginx should redirect https request to an http url if corresponding server doesn't handle https. Or maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182968/nginx-drop-when-server-name-does-not-match/36184058#36184058).

Comment: @RichardSmith it doesn't work. I get no response from the server, when requesting https.com. Looks like, your solution handles all responses instead of being a fallback.