# Why does nginx serve a domain that does not belong?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have this config in nginx...

domain1.com (http, https)
domain2.com (http only)

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain1.com;

    ssl_certificate      /location/of/ssl/domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /location/of/ssl/domain1.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/app/app.sock;
    }
}

# https redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# only http (never https)
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.com;
    root /home/herberthobregon;
}
```

The behavior that I expect is:

http://domain1.com ---> https://domain1.com (nginx does it correctly)

https://domain1.com ---> https://domain1.com (nginx does it correctly)

http://domain2.com ---> http://domain2.com (nginx does it correctly)

but....

> https://domain2.com ---> show content of (*with the chrome warning SSL*)-> https://domain1.com
>   (**nginx doesen't it correctly**)
>
> *and I would expect him not to load anything or show an error*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx drop when server\_name does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182968/nginx-drop-when-server-name-does-not-match)

Comment: the answer of is thread completely blocks the server